# Xamarin Forms iOS WCF delay

Tags: ios, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

We have Xamarin.Forms project which calls WCF Service. 
We have a problem(slow response)calling WCF from iPhone's 4 (with iOS 7.1.2 version). Response is slow only on iPhone's 4.

With another devices it is working quick. We made sure that WCF service is working well (0.1-0.4 sec, but on device side call took from 15 sec to more than 1min). 
The issue occurs on both Debug and Release versions. 
We tried to play with Linker option, but had no success.

Can you help us?

Comment: Some ?s : SSL based request? TLS version? Payload size? `NSURLSession` | `HttpClient`? `Xamarin.iOS` version?

Comment: ssl based request - yes;
TLS version - Apple tls (default) ;
Payload size - 532,719 bytes without image, 742,589 bytes with image;
NSURLSession;
9.8.2.22 - Xamarin.iOS version